# Visual Studio Host Process Required for App to Run Correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008-r2, vshost.exe

I've been asked to move a program from a WinXP machine to Win Server 2008 R2 so that the XP machine can be decommissioned. The program itself is pretty simple: it's a Windows Form App built using VB Express 2010. The form itself really only exists as a container for a single ActiveX control. Once the form is loaded, the ActiveX control is used to capture an image from a thermal camera and then the program is exited.

This all works fine so long as I have the 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' checked for debugging and am running within the Visual Studio Express debugger. As soon as I try to run the app from outside of Visual Studio, or even debug the app without the vshost process running, it fails to connect to the camera and no image is captured.

At this point, I'm looking for the path of least resistance. If I can somehow force the vshost process to run along with the app outside of the debugger, that's just fine. If there's an OS setting I can change to mimic what the host process is doing, or some code I can add to the project itself, that's cool too.

Anyone run across something similar or have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could is possibly be a mismatch between x64 / x86?  If the ActiveX control was compiled as one and the main application as the other, it might behave this way under specific circumstances.  It might be worth compiling as the other architecture and trying it again.

Comment: Nah, that was one of my first thoughts too. Regardless, it's set as x86, which is the correct architecture.